# C++: setw and setfill not behaving predictably

Tags: c++

From my understanding, setw(n) acts by creating a width of n number of characters. On the other hand, setfill('x') allows us to print an n number of x characters.

I am trying to get two rows of stars, like this:

```
**************************************
Woohoo stars!
**************************************
```

In addition, I would like to create two lines of dots of equal length on both sides of a string, like this:

```
....................... TEAR HERE .......................
```

Instead, I am getting something like this:

```
Woohoo stars!
**************************************

.............. TEAR HERE .............................
```

To achieve these goals, I am using the code below with `#include<iomanip>` (note: it is being printed to an external .txt file):

```
//goal 1
outfile << setw(40)<<setfill('*') << endl;  
outfile<< "Woohoo stars!" << endl; 
outfile << setw(40)<<setfill('*') << endl; 

//goal 2
outfile <<setfill('.')<< setw(30) " TEAR HERE " << setfill('.')<< setw(30) <<endl;
```

I have tried reversing the order of `setw` and `setfill` on purpose, but it resulted in the same effect after it was compiled. Furthermore, for the star pattern, the top row does not even get outputted for some reason. Finally, I made sure to do these commands on a new line, so there wouldn't be anything else interfering with the lines they are on.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setw` actually just sets the width of the next thing written to the stream, so the "Tear Here" will be right aligned in a field of width 30.

Solution would be to use:

```
outfile <<setfill('.')<< setw(30) << '.' << " TEAR HERE " << setfill('.')<< setw(30) << '.' <<endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `setw(n)` does not "create a width of n number of characters", it will pad next printed item to n width using specified fill character. You can still make it work like you expected by printing empty string:

```
outfile << setw(40)<<setfill('*') << "" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, wish I could select both yours and Matt's answer.